# CI Ion auth library session not working for different type of user

Tags: session, continuous-integration

I am using   ion auth library in CI application.In application, there are two types of group user admin and staff.It is working fine for login and logout separately but when I logged in staff module it uses same session for admin as well.I mean both user can not logged in at same time in the same browser.

Is there any trick to separate login session for bot user admin and staff?The application should allow to logged in same browser at the same time.

Any help will be great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same browser and have not logged out previous user, It will use that session. You can logout the previous user or different browser for new session.

If its your requirement and you want to achieve this, You will have to set different session keys for different users. Ex.

**For Admin:**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('admin_id', 'VALUEHERE');
```

**For User:**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', 'VALUEHERE');
```

While auth or login you will need to check:

while checking for admin

```
if($this->session->userdata('admin_id'))
{
     //show admin content
}
```

while checking for user

```
 if($this->session->userdata('user_id'))
    {
         //show user content
    }
```